# is there a method to add a interceptor before clipboard paste

Tags: flutter, clipboard

I am looking for a way to add a interceptor, before paste the content of the clipboard, I want add a interceptor which can log the infomation of content.

I have googled many result, but nothing found.

what I am expecting:
for example, add a callback before clipboard paste

```dart
beforePaste(dynamic data) {
...
}
```

then each time of pasting the content of clipboard, `beforePaste` will be called

Comment: I don't think so. However, you could create your own context menu for the text fields and do whatever you want to do in `beforePaste` then paste the clipboard with a package like [`super_clipboard`](https://pub.dev/packages/super_clipboard).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from what you've written, the method you need is not inside the clipboard library. What you should do is handle the pasting task with the textfield you will be working with. You can achieve the scenario you want by using a method that can run before the `onChanged` method. One way to do this is as follows;

```
class CustomFormater extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    print("triggered before textfield changed");
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

And you will use it on textfield you will work on. As shown;

```
TextField(
   onChanged: (y) {
     print("text field changed");
   },
   inputFormatters: [
     CustomFormater(), // here you can use this as interceptor
   ],
),
```

Once you input or paste anything, you will get custom formatter's print value. Then `onChanged` event will be triggered.

Comment: eh, you know pasting file ? that is what I am doing using the clipboard, but not using the textfiled :yum: . it's my fault that I did't provide more information

Comment: oookay. If you wanna provide more information, maybe I can help you better. Good luck :)